# How do I count the number of times a term has occured in the values of a list of JSON objects?

Tags: python, json

I am working on a Python code where I need to put a check on the assignment of a value to a key in a JSON object on the basis of user input. My approach is to create a check using the if-statement on the number of times of the occurrence of the specific key value, for that I need to count the number of times that specific key has already been occurred in the object.

I’ve a list of a large number of JSON objects in python in the following format:

```
[{'name': xyz, 
   'territory': abc, 
    'parameter_a': 1,
    'parameter_b': 2, 
    'parameter_c': 3},
 …]
```

Now I want to count the number of times a specific territory (Say ‘abc’) has occurred in the whole list of json objects. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: A JSON object can hold a specific key only once. So if `key in your_parsed_json` is `True` itmeans `1`, else `0`. If you have the same key twice the JSON is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I’ve a list of a large number of JSON objects in python in the following format:

[{'name': xyz, 'territory': abc,
                           'parameter_a': 1,'parameter_b': 2, 'parameter_c': 3},…]

Now I want to count the number of times a specific territory (Say ‘abc’) has occurred  in the whole list of json objects. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: Please update your question with the formatted example!

Comment: @Alex.Widmore You mean that you want the number of times a term has occured in the _values_ of a JSON object.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan, I'm trying to count the number of times a specific territory  has occurred in the list of json objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do

```
sum((1 for v in json.loads("...") if v.get("territory") == abc))
```

Comment: Alternative, maybe more readable: `sum(v["territory"] == abc for v in json.loads("..."))`